# Formal languages and Automata

Tags: finite-automata, formal-languages

How can one decide for two given DFAs A1 and A2 whether L (A1) = L (A2)?

I do not know how to approach this problem and where to start.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to minimize both A1 and A2. If the resulting minimal DFAs are the same (modulo state names) then A1 and A2 recognise the same language.